# Why I can't connect XML layout file to source code in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I began to learn Android development and can't perform a simple thing. I have an activity_login.xml which defines couples of widgets (TextViews, buttons, etc.) and I want to change textview size programmatically. I' m trying to use R.id but Eclipse don't see my text view. Here what i've tried. TextView in res/layout/activity_login.xml file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/login_text_view"
    android:layout_width="23"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_log"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_sign_up"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    />
```

And here I'm trying to connect to it in my `LoginActivity.java`:

```
final TextView loginTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_text_view);
```

The problem Eclipse don't see neither `loginTextView` nor other widgets in xml file.

Comment: try after `cleaning` the project.

Comment: Did you set the contentView() of your activity first?

Comment: try after Cleaning your project from Project->Clean on Eclipse IDE menu and also do a refresh and close or open because it may be possible you have some error in your xml layouts so R file is not generated. after that in your activity do CTRL+SHFT+O for importing your R instead of android.R

Answer (score 1):

In your activity make sure you set the layout in `onCreate()` using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)`

Answer (score 1):

In `onCreate()`

`setContentView(activity_login.xml)`

[This link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is a good starting point if you haven't already been there. It describes the Android lifecylce and has links to other Android resources when getting started